How to watch out for, steer clear of, ETF swindlers and bankrupts like Emerge Canada?
Me, my husband, kids, grand kids bought $1 million CAD in Emerge ETF's. We just found out  “about Emerge’s alleged misconduct and, from our perspective, the merits of the case remains strong." We invested in Emerge ETF's, as we like Cathie Wood's innovative ETF's.

The funds are branded Emerge ARK because of a partnership with U.S.-based ARK Investment Management LLC, which is run by ARK’S Cathie Wood, a prominent U.S. investor.


A more common refrain, and one echoed by the unitholders we spoke to during our reporting, was that investors would stick with the largest ETF providers in future, or stop investing in ETFs altogether.

Emerge ETF rattled our confidence in Canadian ETF's. We own ETF's with Global X Mirae Asset, Evolve - now we afraid these go insolvent too! We don't want to stop investing in ETF's, but are Mirae Asset and Evolve "largest" enough"?
What lessons can we learn from Emerge ETF's insolvency? How can we protect against future grifters like Emerge?

It feels like failsafes were triggered and all that, not entirely sure what kind of answer you're looking for. Companies fail, sh!t happens, and even if it is rare with investment managers - happens even there.

Primarily:

Diversification. Many investors already diversify across asset classes, geographies, industries, sectors, maturities, time horizons, size of organization, tax characteristics, etc. to reduce risk.
You can also diversify your ETF holdings across a variety of ETF issuers, so that you're not as vulnerable to the risk of one such institution experiencing significant trouble. Within reason, you might also hold your investment assets across different brokerages and banks.
Essentially, don't ever put all your eggs in one basket — and be mindful that there are different kinds of baskets, depending on how you look at the components that make up your portfolio.


Also,

Due diligence. Look into how the ETF issuer is structured. Read through the ETF's prospectus, quarterly and annual reports, and other relevant documents. Focus especially on the parts of those that discuss potential risks, counterparties involved, etc.
But, I wouldn't consider proper due diligence to be a substitute for diversification. Fraud and mismanagement can still occur even when everything looks great on paper.



And remember that if someone is offering returns significantly better than everyone else, there are good odds that this is either a momentary blip, or that they're falsifying the results. Stay with trusted investment houses. The folks on the fringe are there for a reason.
